# How to trigger logout from keycloak in .NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, keycloak, openid-connect

I'm using keycloak to authenticate a user to my ASP.NET Core web app. To log out a user, usually we create a logout button in our ASP.NET Core app. This action will remove cookies and keycloak session of the specific user. Now I wondering if we can trigger a logout action to ASP.NET Core MVC from keycloak user session logout

[image]

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Add an action in your controller and call it:

```
public IActionResult Logout()
    {
        return new SignOutResult(
            new[] { 
                OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme 
            });
    }
```

Comment: yes it work. i realised net/netcore application not immadietely logout when logged out from keycloak server but wait until net/netcore app validate its access token to keycloak server